# Google Sheets Function Converting a Parameter to Upper Case

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

If I pass a variable in Google Sheets Macros into a function, how do I convert that variable to upper case? Examples below do not work (BTW: these are just a subsets of a bigger function)

```
function testit(textComingIn){

var a = textComingIn.toUpperCase();

return a;

}

or 

function testit(textComingIn){

var a = textComingIn.value.toUpperCase();

return a;

}
```

Comment: There should be a function like `UPPER(<your string>)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a simple UpperCase converting function, not a function for use in spreadsheet cells. Try using this myUpper() function:

```
function testNow() {
  var valorCelda = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue();
  Logger.log(valorCelda);
  Logger.log(myUpper(valorCelda));
  Logger.log(valorCelda.toUpperCase());  
}
function myUpper(datopar){
  return datopar.toUpperCase();
}
```

The Log for running this code (uses active cell)... to a text containing cell

```
[20-03-27 20:28:41:614 CST] Dirección de correo electrónico
[20-03-27 20:28:41:619 CST] DIRECCIÓN DE CORREO ELECTRÓNICO
[20-03-27 20:28:41:621 CST] DIRECCIÓN DE CORREO ELECTRÓNICO
```

On a number typed cell throws... TypeError: datopar.toUpperCase is not a function

demonstrating auto typing in JS.

So... use .toString() firt to stringify other values.
Working code is:

```
function testNow() {
  var valorCelda = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue();
  Logger.log(valorCelda);
  Logger.log(myUpper(valorCelda)); // 
  // Logger.log(valorCelda.toUpperCase());
}
function myUpper(datopar){
  return datopar.toString().toUpperCase();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
function onEdit(e) {
if (typeof e.value != 'object') {
e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase());
}}
```

or just selected columns/rows:

```
function onEdit(e) {
var column = e.range.getColumn();
var row = e.range.getRow();
if ( column >=  4 && col <= 10 ) {
if ( row >= 5 ) {
if (typeof e.value != 'object') {
e.range.setValue(e.value.toUpperCase());
}}}}
```

for non-scripted approach use:

```
=UPPER(A1)
```

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UPPER(A1:A))
```